# Why does Java have virtual and not static extension methods like C#?

Tags: c#, java, extension-methods, java-8

The Java language designer decided to use virtual extension methods instead of static extension methods like C#. Static extension methods can lead to naming conflicts with future methods, but interfaces can leaved untouched.

So what were the reasons to use virtual extension methods in Java?

Comment: I believe they serve completely different purposes and are related only by name, so this question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @AntP Static extension methods were introduced in C# to solve the same problem as virtual extension methods do in Java.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Because based on what I'm reading about virtual extension methods in Java, it's pretty clear that they definitely weren't. At all. Not even remotely. Virtual extension methods provide default implementations of methods for interface implementors to defend against future versions of the language (or other APIs, I guess), which has literally nothing to do with what C# extension methods do.

Comment: "Static extension methods can lead to naming conflicts with future methods" - can you clarify? Note that class methods are preferred over extensions during name resolution so class can later decided to implement some extension methods itself (i.e. this is how LINQ optimizations for some types are done - class can implement `Where` to "override" `Enumerable.Where` extension method)

Answer (score 8):

As I've mentioned in the comments, these things serve two completely unrelated purposes. The only thing they have in common is a name.

Java virtual extension methods allow interfaces to declare a default implementation of a method. This is useful if, for example, you release a new version of an API which has additional interface methods but don't want to break all of your API users' implementations of that interface - i.e., for backwards compatibility.

C# extension methods are just a convenient syntax for static methods, so instead of doing:

```
MyStaticMethod(someObject, someOtherObject);
```

You can do:

```
someObject.MyStaticMethod(someOtherObject);
```

Without having to actually change the class implementation of `someObject`. C# extension methods have *nothing* to do with satisfying interface definitions (and *cannot* be used to achieve this goal).

The two things are totally different.

Comment: +1. The main goal of virtual extension methods (default methods) is to facilitate interface evolution. The primary use case in Java 8 is to add streams support to the existing collections libraries. There are several other examples scattered around the Java 8 libraries as well.